Current loop and electromagnetic energy
Take a fixed circular loop of wire in a uniform magnetic field. As far as I can tell, the work we have to do to accelerate the electrons in the wire so a particular current is attained is independent of the orientation of the loop. That is because the magnetic field does no work on moving charges.
However, that observation seems to contradict the dependence of the 'magnetic potential energy' (the magnetic field dotted with the magnetic moment of the loop) on the loop orientation and also the energy stored in the electromagnetic field.
I must be making a simple error somewhere, but I haven't found it yet. How is this contradiction resolved?

If you model the external flux as due to some huge external set of coils (or something like that), then there will be some mutual inductance between the loop and the "external" coils. Accounting for the energy required to maintain a constant external B-field in this way might account for the discrepancy.  I'll try to explore this further if I have time.

Potential energy of current loop $-\mathbf m\cdot \mathbf B_{ext}$ is not the whole energy in the system, because it is linear in current; but already without an external field, the magnetic energy is quadratic in current. More interesting is the comparison of the Poynting field energies - are you sure they are different in the two cases? An argument for the difference would be nice. This is a little hard to see without calculations with specific ugly functions, because to compare energies, we need finite numbers, thus the external field can't be uniform in the whole space.

As you have already mentioned in your answer the magnetic field in this scenario doesn't actually do work on the electrons in order to create the current, that is done by some other mechanism. However, what a uniform magnetic field does to a current loop (essentially a magnetic dipole) is rotate its orientation. You can easily show by considering the Lorentz force on the current loop that the magnetic field causes a torque on the loop, and in fact the torque is always in a direction so as to cause the loop's orientation to be parallel to the magnetic field.
If you placed a magnetic dipole in the same direction as the magnetic field it would not do anything and just stay in its place and orientation because the Lorentz forces would all cancel and because it has no potential energy. However, if you rotated its orientation, it would certainly flip around due to the aforementioned torques created by the magnetic field. This rotation was caused by the magnetic potential energy stored in the dipole due to its orientation.

I think the OP was considering a situation where the loop was fixed in place, and was asking about why the energy stored in the B-field was different in each case.

@MichaelSeifert Ah yes I see however, everything I said still holds true and I believe still answers OP's question. Even if the loop is fixed in place it will continue to have that energy because of the reasons I have explained above. After all if you roll a ball uphill and hold it in place it continues to have potential energy there since the moment you let go it will roll downhill.

Yes, Michael, that's the situation I had in mind. If the loop is allowed to rotate, I believe the current (and thus magnetic moment) decreases so that the total kinetic energy of the loop (including electrons) remains constant. If a battery is hooked up to maintain a constant current, we can extract energy from the battery via the loop as it rotates (does work on us). Again, in this more complicated setup, the electromagnetic field energy / magnetic potential energy has apparently changed, but the only net exchange of energy is between the battery and us.


Take a fixed circular loop of wire in a uniform magnetic field. As far as I can tell, the work we have to do to accelerate the electrons in the wire so a particular current is attained is independent of the orientation of the loop. That is because the magnetic field does no work on moving charges.

Correct. The field does not even have to be uniform, it only has to be static. In theory, we can imagine a source of EMF that does work per unit time $\mathscr{E}I$ that is independent of the details of the static magnetic field the loop is in; if we're worried the magnetic field can affect the source, we get put it in place where the magnetic field is negligible.

However, that observation seems to contradict the dependence of the 'magnetic potential energy' (the magnetic field dotted with the magnetic moment of the loop) on the loop orientation and also the energy stored in the electromagnetic field.

Magnetic potential energy of magnetic moment in external field, given by the formula $-\mathbf m \cdot \mathbf B_{ext}$, is a concept meant for describing energy changes in a restricted class of systems, which, during their motion, do not change their magnetic moment magnitude, only rotate it in space. It cannot give changes of energy correctly for systems whose magnetic moment changes in time, or for a loop with variable current. This is apparent as this expression is linear in current, but the current loop system is expected to have stored energy that is a quadratic function of current (due to self-induction).
Thus the above formula does not give total field energy.
But maybe the total field energy still differs in the two cases? It turns out that no, it does not: if the work done by the EMF source on the current in the circuit is the same, then the stored energy in the field is the same.
In order to check this, we need a general formula for the stored energy in case there is a static field $\mathbf B_{ext}$. Surprisingly, this is not the usual vacuum Poynting magnetic energy $\int_{space} \frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2~dV$, which probably does depend on the orientation of the loop. The assumption we have a static external field, not affected by the loop, leads to a different expression for field energy, which allows for the loop configuration to affect the field energy not only near the loop, but also near the source of the static external magnetic field, and both effects add up to zero.
The formula for stored energy in this case is obtained as follows. We know from EM theory that work per unit time of a perfect EMF source with no internal resistance can be expressed as
$$
\dot{W} = \int_{EMF source} -\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf j_c~ dV,
$$
where $\mathbf j_c$ is the real conduction current in the EMF source, and $\mathbf E$ is electric field. However, in the ideal case of no resistance and no Joule losses, the product vanishes everywhere else, including the conductor, so we can expand the domain of integration to arbitrarily large region $V$:
$$
\dot{W} = \int_{V} -\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf j_c~dV.
$$
Using Maxwell's equations and assuming rate of change of electric field is slow enough, we can assume $\mathbf j_c = \nabla \times \mathbf H$, and we get
$$
\dot{W} = \int_{V} -\mathbf E\cdot \nabla \times \mathbf H~dV.
$$
This integral can be turned into two integrals: a surface integral, which becomes negligible as the region is expanded in all directions far enough, and a volume integral, which gets arbitrarily close to the result:
$$
\dot{W} \approx \int_{V} \mathbf H\cdot \partial_t \mathbf B~dV.
$$
Here, $\mathbf H$ is net magnetic field strength, and $\mathbf B$ is net magnetic induction. Expanding the region $V$ into whole space, we get equality, instead of approximate equality.
If the source of the static external magnetic field is really stiff, so its magnetic field does not change no matter what, we can model it as a hard magnet with constant magnetization $\mathbf M$ that does not respond to change of magnetic field of the loop, and is thus independent of orientation of the loop.
It is useful to express this result using the field $\mathbf H$ only. Since magnetization does not change in time, we have $\partial_t \mathbf B = \mu_0 \partial_t \mathbf H$, and we get
$$
\dot{W} = \int_{space} \mu_0 \mathbf H\cdot \partial_t \mathbf H~dV,
$$
or
$$
\dot{W} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{space} \frac{1}{2}\mu_0 \mathbf H^2~dV.
$$
Since the right-hand side is a simple time derivative, we can integrate in time from the start when $\mathbf H=\mathbf H_{ext}$ to time $t$ and obtain the function $W(t)$:
$$
W(t) =  \int_{space} \frac{1}{2}\mu_0 \mathbf H^2~dV - \int_{space} \frac{1}{2}\mu_0\mathbf H_{ext}^2~dV.
$$
Based on this result, we can define magnetic energy of the system as
$$
E = \int_{space} \frac{1}{2}\mu_0 \mathbf H^2~dV.
$$
This is not the usual Poynting formula one could expect. The reason is, the system is not everywhere the usual medium considered in the derivation/justification of the Poynting definitions(a medium where $\mathbf H$ is linear function of $\mathbf B$). In the hard magnet, the relation between these two fields is not linear, and that's why stored energy in the system is not given by the standard Poynting formula.
We can express this result using the field due to the magnet $\mathbf H_{ext}$ and the field due to the loop $\mathbf B_{loop}$:
$$
E = \int_{space} \frac{1}{2}\mu_0 ( \mathbf H_{ext}^2 + 2 \mathbf H_{ext}\cdot\mathbf H_{loop} + \mathbf H_{loop}^2)~dV.
$$
Here, the first and the second integral is obviously independent of loop's orientation. The only term which maybe could depend on the loop orientation, is (integrating over a finite region $V$):
$$
I = \int_{V} \mu_0 \mathbf H_{ext}\cdot\mathbf H_{loop}~dV.
$$
However, it can be shown this integral goes to zero as the region is expanded to become the whole space. The integrand is a product of a potential field $\mathbf H_{ext} = \nabla \phi_{ext}$ (because $H$-field of a magnet is, due to its curl vanishing everywhere, a potential field) and a solenoidal field $\mathbf H_{loop} = \nabla \times \mathbf A_{loop}/\mu_0$ (because H-field of current loop is simply $\mathbf H_{loop} = \mathbf B_{loop}/\mu_0$), so we have
$$
I = \int_{V} \nabla \phi_{ext} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf A_{loop}~dV.
$$
We can express the integrand as divergence $\nabla\cdot ( \phi_{ext} \nabla \times \mathbf A_{loop})$, and use the Gauss theorem to express the volume integral as a surface integral over the region boundary:
$$
I = \oint_{\Sigma}\ \phi_{ext} \nabla \times \mathbf A_{loop}~\cdot d\boldsymbol{\Sigma}.
$$
At large enough distances from the whole system, we want the integrand to decrease with distance fast enough, so in the limit of integration surface expanded to infinity, the integral will be zero.
The integrand decreases fast enough if the magnet creating the field $\mathbf H_{ext}$ is of finite size; then, at large distances, both the magnet and the loop have "dipolar" $H$-fields - decreasing with distance from the center of the system as $1/r^3$. The integrand then decreases with distance as $\frac{1}{r^5}$, so $I$ goes to zero. If, in contrast,  $\mathbf H_{ext}$ was uniform in the whole space, $\phi_m$ would increase with distance $r$ in direction of the field, and the integrand would fall off only as $1/r^2$, which allows for the possibility that the limit value of the integral $I$ is not zero.
Thus we have shown that work of an ideal battery on current can be thought of as stored in the field energy in the whole space, with value independent of orientation of the circuit. This works when the field energy is defined carefully based on Maxwell's equations and other assumptions. The usual assumptions are that the conductor and EMF source are ideal (no resistance, no Joule losses), but we have a special assumption in particular: the presence of the static external field $\mathbf H_{ext}$, not affected by the current, thus $\mathbf H$ is not a linear function of $\mathbf B$. This lack of linearity invalidates the usual Poynting definition of magnetic field energy density $\frac{1}{2} \mathbf H\cdot \mathbf B$, and requires its alteration (in case of a hard magnet) to $\frac{1}{2}\mu_0 \mathbf H\cdot \mathbf H$ (or some other valid alternative, differing by a constant or expressed in terms of $\mathbf B,\mathbf M$).
A note to validity of the energy density expressions.
In reality, magnets do respond to other bodies creating magnetic field, and alter their magnetization, but the response is often not linear, and manifests hysteresis, so in the magnet, $\mathbf H$ is not even a function of $\mathbf B$ only, but depends on the variable state of the medium (via$\mathbf M$). Then, $\mathbf H\cdot\partial_t\mathbf H$ cannot be written as a time derivative of any function of state, and the derivation of the field energy above fails. Thus neither of the above mentioned expressions for energy density is reliable for systems with real magnets. To derive a correct expression of field energy for such systems, one would have to take into account that there is dissipation of energy in the magnetic medium during changes of its magnetization, which can't be recovered. But then we no longer have a simple ideal system where work is stored in recoverable field energy, but some of the work goes into internal energy, known from thermodynamics. The analysis then gets more complicated.

Thank you very much for your response. Your last equation is what I had in mind. I can see now that it vanishes by symmetry if the external field is uniform. You point out that the field does not have to be uniform. Presumably the integral does not vanish in that case, so there is a difference in field energy. Is that correct?

@TedBurgess You're welcome, it's a very interesting question. I've added an explanation for why the integral vanishes for any static magnetic field of a magnet with finite size (it has to be finite size, otherwise the magnetic field does not decrease with distance fast enough to make the surface integral go to zero).
